# Set of characters in same order in 2 strings

Tags: string, algorithm, substring, matching

I have 2 strings, let's call first one base string and another one as the input string.
I am working to devise an algorithm to find out how many characters of the base string fall in their order inside input string. This means that not all characters from base string might occur in input string but whatever the number of characters are there, should be in order (as they were present in base string)
We need to find out the match percentage of the base string inside input string

Example:

```
base string: abcd
input string: *a*b*c*d*
output: 100%

base string: abcd
input string: *b*c*d*
output: 75%

base string: abcd
input string: *a*c*d*
output: 75%

base string: abcd
input string: *a*c*b*c*d*
output: 75% (*a*c*d* or *b*c*d*)

base string: abcd
input string: *b*a*d*b*c*d*
output: 100% (*a*b*c*d* is found)
```

Comment: In the fourth sample (`*a*c*b*c*d*`) isn't `abcd` present so that you have a 100% match? Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @SelçukCihan abcd is there if you ignore c in the middle of a and b. It can be treated as `(*a*b*c*d*)`

Comment: What will be the maximum length of the base string ?

Comment: @fjardon not fixed

Answer (score 0):

After thinking more on this, this is a typical LCS problem. Percentage can be found out by the ratio of lengths of LCS and Input String/Base String.

As for implementation, I'd using Hirschberg Algorithm.